# Find the Biggest List in a Dictionary of Lists

Tags: c#

Lets say I have:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> ourGroups = new Dictionary(string, List<string>>();
```

Dictionary contents (Key is based on a specific letter position as shown):

**Key**     | **Value** | **Total**

```
-O- | "DOC", "HOP", "POP" | Total = 3
--- | "SIP", "PLZ", "SUZ", "UPS" | Total = 4
```

So key 2 contains our biggest list of values.

**How would I place the biggest key Values into a separate list?** What I tried:

```
List<string> finalGroup = new List<string>();    
finalGroup = ourGroups.Values.Max();
```

Obviously I'm not doing this correctly. A bit of explanation on how this works would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1081785/Get-maximum-value-on-the-dictionary-based-on-the-k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to sort by Values and select the first one like below .

```
var result =   ourGroups.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value.Count()).First().Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to get the **Key**, which has Items in its Value (list), you could use

```
var keyWithMaxValue = ourGroups.Aggregate((l, item) => l.Value.Count > item.Value.Count ? l : item).Key;
```

If you need the Value (list)

```
var maxValue = ourGroups.Aggregate((l, item) => l.Value.Count > item.Value.Count ? l : item).Value;
```

Comment: I appreciate the solutions given. This is my first time using any form of LINQ so still trying to get my head around it.